# Is there an oncomplete event for HTML5 audio?

Tags: javascript, html, audio

Is there an `oncomplete` event for HTML5 audio? I could not find anything on this. I am trying to play a sound after it completes.

Well, specifically I am trying to play through an array of sounds one after the other.

Thanks.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There is the `ended` event . . .

http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#event-media-ended

Example:

```
var audioElement = document.getElementById("myAudio");

audioElement.addEventListener('ended', function() {
    // Audio has ended when this function is executed.
},false);
```

Comment: Multi-page spec link, if your browser’s struggling with the mighty one-page spec: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/video.html#event-media-ended

Comment: Ok thanks.I guess this does not work in the chrome browser?var snd1 = new Audio("sounds/GunShot.mp3");snd1.onended = function(e){

snd1.play();
}

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=30452

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=45074

They seem to be working on it . .

Comment: Not sure since I don't own an Iphone to try but I do know playing audio via the html5 audio tag works (tested on G4) and the mobile safari is pretty up-to-date. . so I'd guess they should have this event handled as well.

Answer (score 21):

The correct way to to this is using the `addEventListener` function:

```
audio.addEventListener('ended', PlayNext);
```