# How can I tell when an HTML5 audio element has finished playing?

Tags: javascript, html, audio

How can I tell when an HTML5 audio element has finished playing?

Does it throw events I can listen to or something similar? I need to react when an audio track ends.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an oncomplete event for HTML5 audio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092266/is-there-an-oncomplete-event-for-html5-audio)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

According to [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_ref_eventattributes.asp), you can use the `onended` event to detect if the audio has finished playing.

In jQuery:

```
$("#player").bind('ended', function(){
    // done playing
    alert("Player stopped");
});
```

For a demonstration see: http://jsfiddle.net/9PCEf/2/

Comment: ...relax man, I couldn't accept the answer yet because enough time hadn't passed yet. I hate when people leave comments like this.

Comment: Wow @thephpdeveloper, you are really thirsty for the tick!

Comment: guys. i was just reminding. i tend to forget on my end and therefore i remind whenever i post an answer. even if it is an answer posted by somebody else i'll remind too. that's what we are doing: moderating our community.

Comment: @thephpdeveloper, would you like to give that tick to me? I really want it... just joking.

Comment: onEnded in React

Answer (score 88):

Using HTML:

```
<audio id="music" src="blah.mp3" onended="yourFunction()"></audio>
```

Using Javascript:

```
document.querySelector("#music").addEventListener("ended", yourFunction, false);
```

Using jQuery:

```
$("#music").on("ended", yourFunction);
```

Read more about [Media events on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events)

Comment: This should be the answer.