# Is a jquery callback available after .play() when using <audio>?

Tags: jquery, audio, callback

Guys how do I play an mp3 file and then another once the first has finished?

I have tried the following without success..

```
$('#file1)[0].play( function () {
   $('#file2)[0].play();
});
```

Can you use callbacks when playing audio?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I tell when an HTML5 audio element has finished playing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9346579/how-can-i-tell-when-an-html5-audio-element-has-finished-playing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling a jQuery method to begin with.

You could attach an event handler to the `"onended"` event:

```
var file = $("#file1");

file.on( "ended", function(){
    $("#file2")[0].play();
});

file[0].play();
```

Answer (score 6):

According to [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_ref_eventattributes.asp), you can use the `onended` event to detect if the HTML5 audio has finished playing.

In jQuery:

```
$("#player").bind('ended', function(){
    // done playing
    alert("Player stopped");
});
```

For a demonstration see: http://jsfiddle.net/9PCEf/2/

You can do the rest after audio playing finished.

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen to the `onended` event.

Answer (score 0):

I used @blasteralfred's code to create a function to play a indefinite series of sound files using jQuery:

```
function playSounds(soundFileIds) {
  if (soundFileIds instanceof Array) {
    var soundFileId = soundFileIds.shift();
    playSound(soundFileId);
    $(soundFileId).bind('ended', function() {
      playSounds(soundFileIds);
    });
  } else {
    playSound(soundFileIds);
  }
}
```

The conditional test for an array allows me to backport this to my existing code that calls this function with just a string. Thanks!