# Playing an array of audio files on page load in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, audio, playback

I am new to JavaScript and this is tripping me up. I just want to play an array of audio files when a page loads. I have tried several different directions and I am not getting the result I need. Can someone help me out? Here is the code I have been trying to make work.

```
var wordOne = new Audio('audio/1111-Pat.mp3');
var wordTwo = new Audio('audio/1112-is.mp3');
var wordThree = new Audio('audio/1113-a.mp3');
var wordFour = new Audio('audio/1114-cat.mp3');

var sentenceOne = [wordOne, wordTwo, wordThree, wordFour];

var readFirst = function () {
    sentenceOne.forEach(function(item, index, array) {
        audio.play();
})
```

Comment: You need to provide far more information. What is happening now? What is the "result you need?" Are the audio files even accessible? Are there errors?

Comment: inside that loop, audio is undefined.

Comment: Sorry. I am very new to this. The audio doesn't play at all. If I do this:

    var wordOne = new Audio('audio/1111-Pat.mp3');
  var wordTwo = new Audio('audio/1112-is.mp3');
  var wordThree = new Audio('audio/1113-a.mp3');
  var wordFour = new Audio('audio/1114-cat.mp3');
 
  var sentenceOne = [wordOne, wordTwo, wordThree, wordFour];
 
 
  function readFirst() {
   wordOne.play();
  };
 
 window.addEventListener('load', readFirst);

The first audio file plays and if I add wordTwo.play() then they both play at the same time. I just need them to play in order one after the other

Comment: Then you'll just want to use a callback function to execute the next audio file. Check out [this question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12298339/is-a-jquery-callback-available-after-play-when-using-audio)