# How to change div background color when .play() is true

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am wanting to change the background color of my div when my audio file is playing and then change it back to its original color when audio is not playing.

```js
$('.uprow2').on('click', function() {
  $('#karma')[0].play();
});
```

```css
.uprow2 {
  width: 680px;
  height: 60px;
  background: #000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="uprow2">
  <p class="song">LISTEN - KARMA POLICE</p>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: See this for how to check when playing the video has ended ► [Is a jquery callback available after .play() when using <audio>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12298339/is-a-jquery-callback-available-after-play-when-using-audio) - This also seems a very good resource for media events you can bind to ► [https://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html](https://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this it would be better to use the events on the `audio` element directly. This way the state will not be hooked to the button, and will still work if the user changes the playing state of the audio file via the player controls. Try this:

```
$('#karma').on('playing', function() {
  $('.uprow2').addClass('playing');      
}).on('ended pause suspend error', function() {
  $('.uprow2').removeClass('playing');
});
```

[**Working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/xakhfmo5/)

Comment: Great! Now I have another question, will this work if I add more audio files to play? Will I be able to target each id or does that require a different code?

Comment: That would depend on what your HTML structure is. I'd suggest starting a new question about it if you have issues

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
$('.uprow2').on('click', function(){
  if ($(this).hasClass('play')) {
    $(this).removeClass('play');
  } else {
    $(this).addClass('play');
  }
});
```

```css
.uprow2 {
width: 680px;
height: 60px;
background-color: #000000;
}

.play {
background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<html>    
<div class="uprow2"><p class="song">LISTEN - KARMA POLICE</p></div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add jQuery code to change background-color for this `div`

```
$(this).css('background-color', 'your-color');
```

Refer below solution:

```js
$('.uprow2').on('click', function(){
  $('#karma')[0].play();
  $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
});
```

```css
.uprow2 {
width: 680px;
height: 60px;
background: #000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>    
<div class="uprow2"><p class="song">LISTEN - KARMA POLICE</p></div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Media events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events) to handle the button background.

```js
var $audioElement = $('#karma');
$audioElement.on('playing abort stalled ended pause suspend error', function(ev) {
    $('.uprow2').toggleClass('myPlayingClass',ev.type == "playing");
});
```

```css
.uprow2 {
  width: 680px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #000000;
  color:white;
  }
.myPlayingClass{
background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="uprow2">
  <audio id="karma" controls  src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/horse.ogg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
  <p class="song">LISTEN - KARMA POLICE</p>
</div>
```