# Jquery play sound and go to next page

Tags: jquery, audio, click

I am trying to figure out how to do this, I want the viewer to click on one of the image, which is inside a apDiv box, then after 3 seconds when the audio finishes, the next page will load.

This is the code it does go to next page, but it does not play the sound, if I remove the setTimeout function the sound plays just fine.

Where did I go wrong?

```
$(function(){
$('#apDiv1').click(

function(){$("#laugh")[0].play();},
function(){setTimeout(function(){window.location = 'page1.html';}, 3900); }
)
 });
```

Comment: Sorry for being late, I read lately your comment, added a nice example how to achieve what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting a timeout, which could lead to different problems, 

use the `audio` event listener `ended` !

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ifafip/1/edit)**</kbd>

```
$(function(){

    function playOnClick(){          
        var sound = $("#laugh")[0];     
        sound.addEventListener('ended', function() {        
           window.location = 'page1.html';        
        }, false);          
        sound.play();          
   }

   $('#apDiv1').click(function(){
       playOnClick();
   });

});
```

Comment: @roXon you _finally_ did it.

Answer (score 1):

You want to write this code as follows

```
$(function(){
    $('#apDiv1').click(function(){
        $("#laugh")[0].play();
        setTimeout(function(){window.location = 'page1.html';}, 3900);
    });
});
```

you could probably utilize the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9346579/how-can-i-tell-when-an-html5-audio-element-has-finished-playing) so that you can swap the sound without having to change the time to `setTimeout`

Comment: Why don't you add an `addEventListener "ended"` to navigate?

Comment: that's because he _might_, sometimes, want to play the sound without the need of redirecting the user afterwards

Comment: @Ejay your comment makes no sense to me, it's about play a sound and --> navigate.

Comment: @roXon that's alright :) actually I now think that I might have misread your comment or misunderstood what you were trying to convey. Can you please add an answer depicting your preferred way of doing it. That'll be a contribution :)

Comment: I am pretty new to Jquery and Html, so most of the time i am brute forcing the codes, there may be easier way, but this ways for for me now, since the audio only lasted for 3 seconds. roXon how do you use the addEventlistener ?

Comment: There you go, added an example.