# how to add listeners to audio elements for continuous playback

Tags: javascript, audio, listener

I have an HTML page with multiple audio elements that I need to play in a continuous was, meaning I need each one to start playing after the previous one finished playing.
How can I assign multiple listeners to do this?

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events - here are all events related to audio files. I think you need to use `ended` event.

Also here is a small example https://stackoverflow.com/a/9376544/1353837

Comment: Yes I am aware of the ended event, but my question is how can I write the code for this in an elegant way?